# Nhibernate - xml column not well formed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, nhibernate

I have some XML snippets that I store via NHibernate (3.2.0.4000) in a SQL Server database. The table column is defined as XML. Storing and Updating of the XML is working, but in the database I am missing the first node with the encoding and version information.

C# object, inner XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RsSn>
  <Layermapping xmlns="someNamespace">
    <Layer layerName="0" layerDescription="5876548" />
    <Layer layerName="1" layerDescription="5876549" />
  </Layermapping>
</RsSn>
```

SQL Server Profiler when the data is inserted:

```
declare @p6 xml
set @p6=convert(xml,
    N'<RsSn><Layermapping xmlns="someNamespace">
    <Layer layerName="0" layerDescription="5876548"/>
    <Layer layerName="1" layerDescription="5876549"/>
    </Layermapping>
    </RsSn>'
    )
```

The **`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`** element is missing!

Content of SQL server column (via SSMS studio):

```
<RsSn>
  <Layermapping xmlns="someNamespace">
    <Layer layerName="0" layerDescription="5876548" />
    <Layer layerName="1" layerDescription="5876549" />
  </Layermapping>
</RsSn>
```

NHibernate Configuration (part of mapping file)

```
<class name="SnippetEntity" table="tblSnippet">
  <id name="SnippetPK" column="SnippetPK" type="Int64">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>

  <property name="ResourceData" column="ResourceData"  type="NHibernate.Type.XmlDocType"/>
</class>
```

I am not allowed to update the NHibernate assembly.

- Is this the correct type that I am using in the mapping file?
- Is there some other configuration I have to use so the document is stored "well formed" in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The top `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` construct is called XML prolog. It is not mandatory to have it. XML is well-formed without it.
2. SQL Server stores XML as Unicode (utf-16). There is no other encoding. That's why SQL Server strips the prolog when it exists in XML.